# How could I install the correct docker-compose version for 1.6.2

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I tried to install docker-compose via https://gist.github.com/wdullaer/f1af16bd7e970389bad3

However, it shows me the exception `ERROR: client and server don't have same version (client : 1.21, server: 1.18)`

How could I install the correct version compose, thanks

## docker help

```
Client version: 1.6.2
Client API version: 1.18
Go version (client): go1.2.1
Git commit (client): 7c8fca2
OS/Arch (client): linux/amd64
Server version: 1.6.2
Server API version: 1.18
Go version (server): go1.2.1
Git commit (server): 7c8fca2
OS/Arch (server): linux/amd64
```

Comment: just `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get upgrade` ?

Answer (score 5):

Seems your docker-compose works fine. The problem is you have different versions of docker client and server.
Why you just don't update docker engine? For that run the following `curl -sSL https://get.docker.com/ | sh` and don't forget to restart your docker service